# How to have multiple names in Apple Mail?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, gmail

In Mail.app I can send e-mails on behalf of different mail addresses.
It looks like this:
[image]

I've achieved this by inputting multiple e-mail addresses separated by a comma in the `Email Address` field of the Account information in the Preferences.

I can also select a full name in the mail preferences:
[image]

However, any name I input there is the same for all three reply-from e-mail addresses.

How can I set a name for each reply-from e-mail address?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Accounts.plist` :

- In **Root** > **MailAccounts** > **Item #** where # is the account to which you want to link the new aliases.
- Create a new ***Array*** called ***EmailAliases***
- In this Array add a ***dictionary*** call ***Item #*** for each name you want
- In each dictionary you created add 2 ***string*** fields : ***name*** and ***alias***.
- In name you put the name and in aliases you put the mail address.
- Restart Mail.app
- Enjoy.

Here is a preview of this in the Xcode plist editor.

[image: Preview in Xcode]

Comment: Sounded good, but unfortunately doesn't work. The reply-from drop down list still only shows the e-mail addresses inputted in the `Email Address` field without any name. The EmailAliases doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: I missed an important point. The EmailAliases Array must be in MailAccounts > Item # where Item # is the account to which you want to link the new aliases.

Comment: Yes, it works now! Thank you for your prolonged attention! Oh, and just a small detail: the string field names are `name` and `alias` (as in your screenshot). Not `aliases` as you write in the fourth point. It's too small for me to edit it, could you please change it so future users don't get confused?

Comment: really helpful! thanks - works on _yosemite_ too.

Comment: I recently upgraded to Mac OS 10.11 and it stopped working. However, the file still incorporates the proposed changes, but the names are not listed anymore. It is also discussed here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3881

Comment: For 10.11 I figured it out: In Mail > Preferences there is now a field: "Alias" where you can add multiple identities.